# react-transform-catch-errors does not look like a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a react project and we are using react starter kit. I am new to the project and when I clone the project from github and start the project using `npm start` it start the server but in web inspector I get following error.

`Uncaught Error: imports[1] for react-transform-catch-errors does not look like a React component.`

People who already working in the project doesn't get this error. But when I ask from one friend to get a new clone and do the same thing I did he also got the same error.

I don't know what details need to post so if anybody need more details please ask.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Finally I found the solution... this is due to version mismatch. I don't have a technical explanation. I found three packages in package json related to this problem

```
"react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.0",
"react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.1",
"redbox-react": "^1.1.1",
```

so what I did was removed the `^` which download the latest version. Also removed already installed `node-modules` folder and ran `npm cache clear`.

After that I ran `npm install` and the issue gone. I'm a happy lad :D

Comment: Correct answer. The offending package is `redbox-react`, so you can just edit that. Also removing the "^" doesn't download the latest version, it downloads exactly the same version (in this case, 1.1.1).

Comment: Thanx. Removing "^" is the solution but still could not understand it as it installs the same version

Answer (score 13):

This happened on my project when redbox-react updated itself from 1.2.6 to 1.2.7.

I've now set npm shrinkwrap to only ever get v1.2.6 of redbox-react

Comment: indeed, that's the cause

Comment: This was the underlying cause for me as well. Thanks!